# Question about texture packs

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

So this is my question. My brother and I always play minecraft together on our iPads. I saw that there is texture packs and we both want them but he no longer has money on his gift card, however I do. If I buy the texture pack and make a world, will he be able to view the texture pack, like I can? Thank you

Comment: Note that not all texture/resource packs cost money, you shouldn't have to pay for one.

Comment: Stated in the Minecraft tag description: "This tag is for (vanilla) Minecraft on the PC."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the texture pack is only enabled for the purchaser. Your brother must purchase the texture pack if he would like to use it.

Answer (score 1):

No, the texture pack is client side. You will see the textures. He will not.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Only the purchaser can view the packs.